# Is it possible to generate and run a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Long story short, I am working within a framework that automatically calls a function named `[formname]_success()` upon a successful form submission. Normally the form is built server side and the form and success function both sit in the page source.

In this case, however, I am dynamically creating (and naming) a form client side, however I do not know how to dynamically add a function named `[formname]_success()` that can then be called immediately after a successful submission. Right now the code checks to see if `[formname]_success()` exists, sees that it does not and therefore does not attempt to call it.

Is it possible to dynamically write a js function to the HTML document such that it can be called immediately afterwards?

I am familiar with variable function names and how they work, but I don't think it applies here.

I am not in a position where I can change the nature of the success function call from the framework.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply put yes, you can.  What programing language are you using?

Comment: a code sample would be very helpful to understand what problem you are describing

Comment: `eval` could be abused to do it, I suppose. Maybe `window[variable + '_success'] = function() {}` but I can't vouch for that.

Answer (score -1):

if the function is in the global scope you could use `window['[form_name]_functionname'] = function(){ return true;}`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, with the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) creator

```js
// Create a function that takes two arguments and returns the sum of those arguments
var adder = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');

// Call the function
console.log(adder(2, 6));
```

Comment: Why the down vote? This is exactly what the OP was looking for.